# Call Functions regular every Month

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, date

For a application with a database in C#, I need to call a function every month just once(on a defined day). It is necessary to check on every start of the application, if the defined day, which is registered in the database, has already been this month and if that, not to call the method again. 
What would be the best way to solve? Save month and year in the database too and check if actual date > than the values in the database?

Is there a more easy way?

**EDIT 1:**

If I try to do that with the Windows Task scheduler, how can I contact that with C#?
My method is a Sql-Insert-Statement, that has to be done every month once on the same day.

Comment: Do you HAVE to do it in the app? Could you not schedule a SQL job in the database.

Comment: Yes, I have to do it in the App!

Comment: When you say function do you mean a SQL function?  Later you refer to method?   What are you calling and what are you passing to it (if anything)?    What type of C# app?  Is it a console application?   Your problem statement would be clearer with "For a C# application with a database".

Comment: @user896692 If you "method is a Sql-Insert-Statement" then why do you have to do it in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scheduled task, windows service or sql server agent would be better (if you have a server available).

Failing that - and provided that the function doesn't *have* to run on a specific day, then your solution above seems fine.

If the function *must* run on the 1st can you rely on your app being 'on' at that time?

**edit:** so....you have some kind of c# application with an mdf in folder somewhere. You have an insert that must run on the 1st of the month.

I would [create a scheduled task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx) on the machine that has the app. The task would call another (tiny) C# program (.exe)  command that has a connection string to your db*. This app gets called once a month and does the insert.

*`Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\asd\qwe\mydbfile.mdf; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes`

Comment: But I have to do it in my programm, every time it starts, I have to check if it has already be done this month or not. 
Besides, the database is a .mdf file in my application.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a windows service for something that only runs once a month...

Answer (score 3):

Use the [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) and setup a recurring [job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187880.aspx).

If this is not an option, you can use the [windows task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) to execute a [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) script.

Answer (score 1):

For something as specific as that why not just create a scheduled task to invoke your app.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with a scheduled task?

Comment: @user896692 - He means the [windows task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

You could save the data in the database as you suggest and just write something that you can call via Windows Scheduler.  I'm sure others will offer other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question as you.My solution as follow:
Put this action in Main() to insure calling this method every time,and judge DateTime.Now  is the first day of month ,if yes ,do something about your business.

My English is poor.